# Robo test question: How to get the app to open a deeplink first before start testing actions defined in robo script?

Tags: android, testing, firebase-test-lab, gui-testing

I have a deeplink and can use `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "DEEPLINK_XXX"` in command line to directly open a screen in my app.

The Goal is to use Robo Script to auto test a few defined interactions(clicks) **after** using deeplink to open the specific screen.

I uploaded my apk and the pre-recorded robo script to Firebase TestLab and in configuration I added the [deeplink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01GH6.png). I found it was triggering the script right after open the app and only go to the deeplink at the end.

Is there a way to tell TestLab to first open the deeplink and execute the robo script after?

I've tried changing the condition of contextDescriptor to `non_roboscript_action_performed` or `element_present`
"contextDescriptor": {
"condition": "non_roboscript_action_performed"
},
but unfortunately neither works.

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

You can add ADB_SHELL_COMMAND as the first action of your Roboscript to open the deeplink (rather than specifying this deeplink in the test configuration). Then, the rest of the Roboscript will be performed after opening the deeplink.

```
{
  "eventType": "ADB_SHELL_COMMAND",
  "command": "am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'DEEPLINK_XXX'"
},
```